# Can't see Materialized Views from a Linked Server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, materialized-views

I have an SQL Server 2008 Express Edition and added an Oracle DB as a linked server with the `OraOLEDB.Oracle` provider. The connection works but I can only see the views from the Oracle server, no tables, and no materialized views.

I can `SELECT *` on the visible views, so there doesn't seem to be an obvious problem with the linking.

Comment: if you connect to Oracle (directly, not through SQL Server) with the same user as SQL Sever uses to connect to Oracle, can you select from the Materialized Views?

Comment: Yes, when I connect through PL/SQL Developer I can see all the tables and materialized views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:** I was looking for the tables and materialized views in SQL Management Studio in the Object Explorer tree, which only showed me the "normal" views. I opened the Object Explorer Details view (F7) and there they all were: tables and views. The materialized views are also displayed under tables.